# RubyMine fails to find github repository

Tags: github, rubymine

I am testing out RubyMine from JetBrains as a potential new IDE to use for rails development.

I am trying to checkout from version control using github. But when I try to checkout my repository by url (which works on my cloud 9 environment), I get "Clone Failed repository not found".

I have tried the various suggestions on the web like setting SSH executible in the Git settings to "Native".

I have tried using both token and username password in the github settings.

I have tried "clone github repositories using SSH" and combinations of all of these.

Has anyone gotten RubyMine to work with github on a mac?

Thanks.